# How to register a TypeSerializer with Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink with Scala, and to get a better support for state migration I decided to move away from "let Flink handle everything with introspection" to having more explicit serialization/deserialization. This way when I make a change to my classes, I can decide how to handle the differences in my ser/deser.

So I decided to go with Avro, mostly following advices I found in this article: https://medium.com/wbaa/making-sense-of-apache-flink-state-migration-with-scala-and-avro-69091c232646

And taking inspiration from this example project: https://github.com/mrooding/flink-avro-state-serialization

Reading the article I can understand how to use a custom serializer when I am creating a state explicitely within a function.

For example I could write this when defining a state:

```
  private[this] lazy val stateDescriptor: ValueStateDescriptor[Product] =
    new ValueStateDescriptor[Product]("product-join", Product.serializer)
  private[this] lazy val state: ValueState[Product] = getRuntimeContext.getState(stateDescriptor)
```

The problem is, I don't know how to register the serializer when Flink implicitely creates a state from my pipeline. For example, if I create a `FlatMapFunction[T, O]` Flink will create a state with types `T` and `O` to save the instances in-between blocks. And in this case, it will still do introspection because I don't know how to tell Flink to use my `TypeSerializer` instead.

I found documentation to register a Kryo type with the `StreamExecutionEnvironment`, but not a `TypeSerializer`. My goal is not to use Kryo but Avro directly.

So how would I go to register a `TypeSerializer` globally on my environment, so Flink knows to use it instead of using introspection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a TypeInfoFactory and annotate your type with @TypeInfo. The factory needs to return a TypeInformation, which acts as a sort-of factory for TypeSerializers.

Comment: Thank you! I found this: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeInformation.html

Should I implement all methods by myself, or is there one of the subclass convenient to describe a Scala case class?

Comment: Flink has a built-in type info for case classes (CaseClassTypeInfo); why can't you use that / why do you need a custom serializer?
Regardless, you could base it on the BasicTypeInfo.

Comment: The CaseClassTypeInfo seems to break state each time I add a field, and I want to be able to release changes to my pipeline without discarding the state

Comment: Did you check whether the CaseClassTypeInfo is actually used by Flink? (or rather the inverse, that Kryo is not used?)
Can you expand on what kind of state your job actually has? A common trap we see is users putting a CaseClass within an Option/List etc, which also go completely through Kryo.